# Is there any difference between workon venv and venv\Scripts\activate

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtual-environment

Is there any difference between `workon venv` and `venv\Scripts\activate`?

Answer (score 0):

[workon](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#workon) comes from [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/). This is just a wrapper around virtualenv.

`venv\Scripts\activate` is the default way to activate a `virtualenv` when not using a library or wrapper like [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/)